# Large File Uploading?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an excel file with two sheets containing more then 150 columns. When I try to upload this file into the server using file upload control, I am geting an error saying "bad request". This is the code I am working on.

```
protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path;
    if (FUExcel.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            path = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\UploadedFiles\\" + Guid.NewGuid() + FUExcel.FileName;
            FUExcel.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
            Server.ScriptTimeout = 4000;
            LblMsg.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";                  
            ExcelLOBServices.ExcelSheetNames(path);                  
            ExcelLOBServices.columnNamessheet1(path);
            ExcelLOBServices.columnNamessheet2(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LblMsg.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can any one help me with this.......when i try to upload in the browser its...."HTTP BAD REQUEST".

Comment: Can you debug through the BtnSubmit_Click event handler? Also use _Path.Combine_ to create a file path.

Comment: nope its not going till there ......m geting bad request in the browser itself

Comment: Can you upload a smaller file?

Comment: yes i can upload a smaller file

Answer (score 1):

The default max file upload size is only about 4MB in ASP.NET. You'll need to update your web.config to allow larger sizes. If you wanted to allow say, 20MB you could do:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>
```

Read more here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="2895168" />...i tried this changes but its not wotkin ...same error aging

Comment: sure where did you upload it to?

Comment: to the server.....i had created a folder named "UPLOADEDFILES" where all the files uploaded should be stored for now

Comment: I'm sorry Raghu but I don't know the address to your server, you'll need to provide a link or at least a URL. Ideally though you could just edit your question to include the relevant part of the file.

Comment: When you say you uploaded it to "the server" what server are you talking about?

Comment: I can't download files from your local server.

Comment: You wanted me to look at your ASPX file! Forget it this conversation is just too frustrating. I can see we aren't understanding each other and I have to go to bed.

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config you need to update the maxrequest length. By default it is set to 4096 (4 Mb).

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="2895168" />...i tried this changes but its not wotkin ...same error aging

Comment: Does the user running the application pool have write access to the location you are trying to save the file?